# Is there a way to compile the bodies of stored procedures together through SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, sql-server-2008

I don't have the permission to use EXEC to call stored procedures on a SQL Server DB. There is a particular stack/nest of procedures that I need to use in debugging so normally I open the driver proc which calls all others and slowly work through it copying the body of the procs into one big SQL file. I do save the compiled sections of SQL once it's in the big file, but the procs may be changed in the mean time resulting in my having to put it all together with the fresh/current code again.

Is there a way an easier way to convert

```
EXEC proc1
EXEC proc2
```

into

```
<proc1 body SQL>
<proc2 body SQL>
```

using sp_helptext or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by convert? You want the procedure body to copy?

Comment: I mean you must obtain appropriate privileges to do your job. Contact you sql server administrator.

Comment: My current method is:
1. Ready 'EXEC proc1'
2. Go copy the body of proc1 (the actual code that's executed when you call 'EXEC proc1')
3. Paste it into the file
4. Repeat steps 1-3 for every proc called

I just want to improve on that process and hopefully make it less manual.

The reason I don't have DB permissions to do this is I'm a developer attempting to help the QA people. I don't have access on the QA servers like I do on the dev servers.

Comment: That should not be an issue; in most cases DEV and QA DB structure will be same; only the data will vary (QA DB likely to have good data volume for ease of testing). in that case, just get those procs from QA DB -> build them on DEV DB -> execute them against DEV Db and do your testing.